# Why is my variable 'D8' getting updated in in the second line?

Tags: python, variables, variable-assignment

```
D8 = D7

D7[np.eye(D7.shape[0], D7.shape[1]).astype('bool')] = np.nan
```

I want to save D7 as D8 before the second line, but running the second line somehow changes D8???

I'm lost as to why this is happening.

I expected D8 to remain the same after the second line, but I am getting NaN along the diagonals in both D7 and D8 when I only want it in D7.

Comment: D8 is just another name for the same object that D7 is the name for

Comment: `D8` is a reference to `D7`, not a copy.  If you want a true copy of `D7`, use `D8 = D7.copy()`.

Answer (score 0):

D8 is a reference to D7, not a copy. If you want a true copy of D7, use D8 = D7.copy().

– MattDMo 7 mins ago

Thank you MattDMo!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).